# When removing a source from MediatorLiveData, does the associated Observer get removed as well?

Tags: android, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

When removing a source from MediatorLiveData, does the associated Observer get removed as well?

```
private final MediatorLiveData<Model> liveModel = new MediatorLiveData<>();
private LiveData<ModelEntity> liveData = repository.getModelEntity();

    liveModel.addSource(liveData , new Observer<ModelEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ModelEntity modelEntity) {}
    });

liveModel.removeSource(liveData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you call `removeSource` the Observer callback is removed.

Internally it calls:

```
mLiveData.removeObserver(this);
```

You can check the line [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.java;l=148;drc=48a64a1a54a8140fa89a511cb31507aa537c0fec), `unplug()` function is called from `removeSource`